# Impala SQL LEFT ANTI JOIN

Tags: sql, impala

Goal is to find the empid's for a given timerange that are present in LEFT table but not in RIGHT table.
I have the following two Impala queries which I ran and got different results?

```
QUERY 1: select count(dbonetable.empid), COUNT(DISTINCT dbtwotable.empid) from 
(select distinct dbonetable.empid 
from dbonedbtable dbonetable
WHERE (dbonetable.expiration_dt >= '2009-01-01' OR dbonetable.expiration_dt IS NULL) AND dbonetable.effective_dt <= '2019-01-01' AND dbonetable.empid IS NOT NULL) dbonetable
LEFT join dbtwodbtable dbtwotable ON dbonetable.empid = dbtwotable.empid

--43324489  43270569


QUERY 2: select count(*) from (
select distinct dbonetable.empid from dbonedbtable dbonetable
LEFT ANTI join dbtwodbtable dbtwotable ON dbonetable.empid = dbtwotable.empid
AND (dbonetable.expiration_dt >= '2009-01-01' OR dbonetable.expiration_dt IS NULL) AND dbonetable.effective_dt <= '2019-01-01' AND dbonetable.empid IS NOT NULL) tab
--19088973

--For LEFT ANTI JOIN, this clause returns those values from the left-hand table that have no matching value in the right-hand table.
```

To explain the Context,
Query 2: Trying to find all the empid's that are in dbonetable and are not in dbtwotable using LEFT ANTI JOIN which I learned from here:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_joins.html
--For LEFT ANTI JOIN, this clause returns those values from the left-hand table that have no matching value in the right-hand table.

And in Query 1:
The dbOnetable calculated based on where clause and results from it are LEFT OUTER joined with dbtwotable, And on top of that result, I am doing a count(dbonetable.empid) and COUNT(DISTINCT dbtwotable.empid) which gave me a result as --43324489  43270569, which means 53,920.
My question either my Query 1 result should be 43324489 -43270569 = 53,920 or my Query 2 Result should be 19088973.

what could be missing here, is my Query 1 is incorrect? Or is my LEFT ANTI JOIN is misleading?
Thank you all in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's different because you forgot specifying "where dbtwotable.empid is null" in the query 1

Additionally, your query 2 is logically different from query 1 because in query 1, you join only on equivalence of empid1 and empid2, while in query 2 your join has much more conditions, so the tables have much fewer common entries compared to query 1, and as a result, the final count is much larger.
If you make a join condition in query 2 the same as in query 1 and put everything else into where clause, you will get the same count that you got in query 1 (updated) which is 53920. That's the count you need

Comment: Hello Mangusta,
It should be something like below in Query 1?
```
select count(dbonetable.empid), COUNT(DISTINCT dbtwotable.empid) from 
(select distinct dbonetable.empid 
from dbonedbtable dbonetable
WHERE (dbonetable.expiration_dt >= '2009-01-01' OR dbonetable.expiration_dt IS NULL) AND dbonetable.effective_dt <= '2019-01-01' AND dbonetable.empid IS NOT NULL) dbonetable
LEFT join dbtwodbtable dbtwotable ON dbonetable.empid = dbtwotable.empid WHERE dbtwotable.empid IS NULL 

```

Comment: yes. your query 1 gets all entries in dbtable1 regardless of whether they are in dbtable2 or not. after doing left join you are only interested in entries for which "dbtable2.empid" is null. that's the way how you get entries which are in dbtable1 but not in dbtable2

Comment: Perfect, I totally get it my bad. But doing that resulted in 
Col1       Col2
--53920 0.
And its still not matching with Query 2 result.

Comment: Hey Mangusta,
Yes, that's correct, Awesome.

select count(dbtableone.empid), COUNT(DISTINCT dbtabletwo.empid) from 
(select distinct dbtableone.empid 
from dbonedbtable dbtableone
WHERE (dbtableone.expiration_dt >= '2009-01-01' OR dbtableone.expiration_dt IS NULL) AND dbtableone.effective_dt <= '2019-01-01' AND dbtableone.empid IS NOT NULL) dbtableone
LEFT join dbtwodbtable dbtabletwo ON dbtableone.empid = dbtabletwo.empid WHERE dbtabletwo.empid is null;
--53920 0

Comment: Q2:
select count(*) from (
select distinct empid from dbonedbtable WHERE (expiration_dt >= '2009-01-01' OR expiration_dt IS NULL) AND effective_dt <= '2019-01-01' AND empid IS NOT NULL) dbtableone
LEFT ANTI join dbtwodbtable dbtabletwo ON dbtableone.empid = dbtabletwo.empid

Comment: Yes Mangusta, I thought I've pasted the count.

Comment: Hey Mangusta, Sure thing Man. Thank you for Help, I should've done that before you even asked, but I was out.